# Does any country have real plans for a manned mission to Mars?

Tags: mars, crewed-spaceflight

I'm curious as to whether or not any country has any real plans for a manned mission to Mars. Not a conceptual thing, but real, hard plans. If so, are there any specifics?

Comment: What is the difference between a concept and a hard plan?

Comment: Concept: "We might be able to stuff a bunch of people into a space tub somewhere in the next half-century" Plan: "We have most of the technology to do this, and are anticipating doing this around 2018"

Comment: NASA has had 'plans' since it was created in 1958.  Every unmanned mission to Mars you see, in one way or another, is regarded as a precursor to an 'eventual' manned mission.  What you really want to know is does anyone have a plan that is authorized (given 'Authority To Proceed')AND budgeted with real spendable money.  The answer, to each, is NO.  No nation on Earth has an announced, authorized and budgeted project in existence to send people to Mars.  Do not expect one in the US until the Federal Budget is at least balanced, Elon MKusk and the Mars One project notwithstanding.  Sorry.

Comment: I think the real answer to your question is, "No, or at least, no country has made such plans public".  Nobody has a *credible* plan to take humans to Mars (I added "credible" because, Mars One is not credible). Ultimately the issue is money - we'd need someone, or some group, to fund the ~$20 billion - $80 billion USD that is likely required for such a project.

Comment: If "real plan" means, they're building the ship, then, I think the answer is clearly no.     To quote the great George Wendt in a very silly movie when he kidnapped himself, only to find his house surrounded by cops and his life in danger.   "I now know the difference between an idea and a plan"    There's lots of ideas out there, but "real plans" for manned (or womaned) missions to mars - that's a no.

While not nearly as romantic, unmanned missions are so so so much easier.  No food, no oxygen, no water, no human waste - much less mass needs transport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of a country, but [Mars One are looking for volunteers](http://www.news.com.au/technology/sci-tech/wanted-humans-to-for-mars-colony-mission/story-fn5fsgyc-1226552015338) to send someone.

Sorry to extend your question to corporations rather than "countries" (assuming government-led).

Comment: Mars One is a publicity stunt run mostly by PR people who make fancy graphics and want to make a reality show (filmed on Earth).

Comment: And a follow up to the Mars One organization, or lack thereof.  https://medium.com/matter/mars-one-insider-quits-dangerously-flawed-project-2dfef95217d3

Comment: Mars One is a gimmick.  An entertaining gimmick no doubt, but a gimmick.  I'm also not sure how this answers the question in any real way.  @user6972's answer, while flawed itself, is light-years better.

Comment: @user6972 Thanks for calling my MSc thesis a "fancy graphics reality show on earth". While the problem is obviously larger than people willing to admit, and without Russians pushing you from behind it's not easy to get a 8 year strict deadline, Mars One is still on track. And while I have no doubt it will probably be delayed much behind 2030 - I do think it will eventually launch in the 2030 decade.

Comment: @paul23 I don't know anything about your thesis.  I'm referring to the Mars One program and their progress to date and what little technical information they've published.

Answer (score 0):

Something not discussed much is we currently do not have the technology to depart earth, land on Mars, and then again depart Mars.  There is way too much fuel required for such a round trip.

Right now with our chemical rockets it is strictly a one way trip.  The definition of a suicide mission.  So people may talk and speculate, but I doubt anyone is going to seriously spend the kind of money needed in the hopes there might be qualified people who would actually accept the mission (ethical issues aside).

For those who would like to read more about the challenges this type of mission must solve before we can even leave the atmosphere I suggest you read [Robert Braun's paper](http://www.marsdrive.com/Libraries/Downloads/Mars_Exploration_Entry_Descent_and_Landing_Challenges.sflb.ashx) on the subject.  Or at least read [something lighter by wired](http://www.wired.co.uk/news/archive/2013-05/31/getting-to-mars) which covers a wide range of challenges many of which we still haven't technically found proven solutions for.

EDIT:  Undo specifically stated is there any real plan which means: "We have most of the technology to do this, and are anticipating doing this around 2018"

Since people don't seem to read the links...The honest answer is no, we don't have the technology (meaning "application of scientific knowledge for practical purposes") to do this.  We *think* we understand the *some* of issues well enough to investigate building the hardware.  Since no human has left earth orbit, survived in space and returned to earth, no one can even claim we understand all the technical hurdles. Even long term experiments in isolated biospheres in the Earth's gravity, atmosphere and sunlight have failed miserably.

In fact it wasn't until 2005 that we realized it was impossible to send a chemical rocket there and back.  Yet ask the general public in 2004 and they would tell you we have the technology to do it--build a big rocket.

And this is an illustration of why it seems our progress to voyage into space has stalled.  Not because it would just cost too much, but we do lack technology knowledge in many areas for such a trip.

As an example: NASA's popular solution barring a technology breakthrough is to use heavy lift rockets (which we don't have yet) to build the ship in space and haul all the mass out there first then launch from there.  Do we know how to build a ship in space?  Not really, but ISS has taught us a lot about what we don't know any we can start looking at tools to develop the technology for exo-construction.  But we (humans in general) are way too early in the technological process to claim we can go to Mars and back by year XXXX.

EDIT2:  As a recent follow-up on Feb. 2015, Gerard ’t Hooft, a Dutch Nobel laureate and ambassador for Mars One project, said he did not believe the mission could take off by 2024 as planned.

“It will take quite a bit longer and be quite a bit more expensive. When they first asked me to be involved I told them ‘you have to put a zero after everything’,” he said, implying that a launch date **100 years from now** with a budget of tens of billions of dollars would be an achievable goal.

http://www.theguardian.com/science/2015/feb/23/mars-one-plan-colonise-red-planet-unrealistic-leading-supporter

Comment: @Erik how so?  Are you talking fuel or serious investors willing to pay to send people on a one-way trip?  Mars one needs $6 billion...they'll never get it.  Not to mention they have no serious technology to allow for long term (indefinite) food supplies, maintenance, fuel or water.

Comment: "...we currently do not have the technology to depart earth, land on Mars, and then again depart Mars."  This is simply not true.

Comment: @Erik it is absolutely the cold hard facts.  All return maned flight concepts require fuel production on Mars (or refueling somewhere outside of earth that doesn't exist today) which is not provable or testable until they land, fire up the nuclear reactor (they'll need tons of power) and then try running the fuel production gear (which also assumes there is a decent H2O source near the landing site).  Thus current technology isn't ready to go there and back without taking a massive risk in untested (on mars) technology and ideal mars conditions that they can produce their own fuel to return.

Comment: @Erik you can see from this paper in situ fuel production on Mars is still speculative.  You might not be able to read this if you're not a member of ieee: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=1559325

Comment: In situ fuel production would be great, but it is not necessary.

Comment: @Erik you'll have to do more than just down vote and say I'm wrong.  A little evidence would be nice.  Have other people found enough water to produce fuel?  Has any fuel actually been produced on mars?  No.  So no one can even claim they have the tools/ability to make fuel and the delta-v required to lift all that fuel from the earth, then again the deta-v to land with all that fuel then launch again with all that fuel...it's just not possible to carry all that mass.

Comment: I'm not going to do your research for you.  You can simply do the math and you will find that sending the propellant for the return trip, while expensive, isn't impossible.  It's actually more expensive to go to the moon in terms of delta-v required.  Furthermore, ISRU isn't beyond our current tech.  ISRU only provides fuel for the ascent stage anyway.

Comment: @Erik how about you do some research for yourself?  No ship in existence can carry all the required mass.  And ISRU has never been tested on mars so you can't say it can be done.  There may not even be enough water...then what?  Here's a popularization of the issues for you http://www.wired.co.uk/news/archive/2013-05/31/getting-to-mars

Comment: I'm sorry you don't like the downvote.  It's not personal.

Comment: My issue is it's not useful if you can't explain why.  Even the article says "We currently don't have the capability to land people on Mars, plain and simple. This is a fairly recently recognised problem, having only been understood through calculations made in the early 2000s."

Comment: “We’ve maxed out our ability [with the 1 ton Curiosity rover] to take mass to the surface of Mars,” said engineer Bobby Braun, former NASA chief technologist and co-author of a 2005 research paper highlighting this problem.  Anything more massive, including a human mission, which NASA estimates would require landing at least 40 to 80 tons of machinery, is completely out of the question.

Comment: You seem to confuse what is possible technologically with what is possible with existing launch vehicles much less multiple flights and, well, thinking harder than some civil servant almost ten years ago.  Having said that, goodnight.

Comment: @Erik the quotes were from 2013 and 2011.  The paper is 2005.  I think you're just trolling.

Comment: It does appear that the only reason we won't currently do it is that the cost/benefit tradeoff is not worth it. Technologically, as Erik says, there is nothing to stop us sending craft there, sending tankers with fuel if necessary etc. It would be exorbitant, but we could do it.

Comment: It's a matter of interpretation of *do we have the technology*.  We don't have the vehicles.  We could develop them, but we don't currently have them.  I guess that's where the difference in interpretation stems from.

Comment: It depends if you consider untested exo-planet prototypes, ideas and concepts as "having the technology".  We are probably 15-20 years away from understanding solutions to "having the technology".  All we have now are mostly a collection concepts and ideas.

Comment: Writers often use the word 'technology' when they really mean (or should say) 'equipment'.  I would not read too much into negative statements if thew writer is careless inb that way.

Comment: I gave -1 for the statement that we don't have the technology due to fuel requirements being untrue. While there may be other technologies that we lack for long-term habitation on mars, existing rocket technology is sufficient for multi-launch missions where the fuel and ascent vehicle, the Mars descent vehicle, and trans-Martian habitate are launched separately.  The total number of launches might be relatively high, although using a Saturn V or Energia-class rocket would likely make it possible in 3 - 5 launches. Clearly the issue is money and not the technology.

Comment: Additionally, @user6972, you wrote (in a reply to Erik), " No ship in existence can carry all the required mass". Not having a current rocket is not the same as not having the technology. The Saturn V and Energia rockets were launched in the 1960s and 1980s respectively, and given multiple launches, could take the the propellent and ascent vehicles (possibly separately) to Mars. Smaller rockets could work too, it's just a matter of more launches. Even if nobody today has a wooden sailing ship capable of crossing the ocean doesn't mean we lack the technology to make on. Ditto for Mars rockets.

Comment: +1, This is the right answer. All you downvoters, you are naive. For example, @Kirkaiya's *it's just a matter of more launches*. Using "just" or "simply" is just simply wrong. There are many, many aspects of sending a human mission to Mars where the humans eventually arrive back to Earth that we do not know how to do (yet). We might know how to do that a decade or two (or more) from now, but for now, we don't know how to do that. What about sending humans to Mars and leaving them there (e.g., the bogus *Mars One* program)? We'll be leaving them there to die, and in rather short order.

Comment: @Kirkaiya I would simply posit that saying you can build a wooden ship capable of crossing the ocean is meaningless in terms of technology if said ship has never been built, tested or even sailed.  Bragging, yes, real technology no.  Humans have never left near orbit of the Earth, so to say we know exactly how to do it and the technology is ready, is naive at best.  A lot more work and testing needs be done before we can make a solid claim of being ready for interplanetary travel.  Sending 5 launches of cargo is not equal to 1 cargo of humans.

Comment: @user6972 It seems futile arguing with you, since you've got a thorough understanding of modern technology and even Bobby Braun to back you up. I would, however, point you to this program from the 60's called the 'Apollo program'. It was a combination research/exploration program, which of course no one reads about because no one's interested in that stuff! But you might be surprised to learn that they actually built a heavy lift launch vehicle, landed humans on another world, had them live there for a couple days, and brought them back! All the tech was there in the 60's, just not the SCALE!

Comment: @user6972 No, you are incorrect. Technology and specific vehicles are different things.  Your view of what "technology" is leads to ridiculous conclusions:  by your argument, we didn't have the technology to land people on the Moon until the instant that the Eagle lander touched down.  That's clearly nonsense - even if it didn't actually land, the technology was obviously available.  Nobody has ever used a MIRV'd set of nuclear warheads on populated cities, but nobody (bar you) would claim we don't have that technology.  You're being ridiculous - we quite clearly have the technology.

Comment: @DavidHammen Your obvious use of a straw man (Mars One?  Hahahah, what a joke) does not make your point any better.  All the technology to send humans on a short mission to Mars exists, and most of it has been demonstrated, including the in-orbit assembly and docking required by using multiple, smaller launches.  This answer is wrong, and the negative score that it has is pretty clear evidence that most others agree with me, and that the consensus view is that the limiting factor is money and not technology.

Comment: @Kirkaiya - We quite clearly do not have the technology. That's why NASA's plans are for a trip to and from Mars trip in the mid 2030s. Maybe. There are a number of needed technologies that are still very low TRL, TRL 1-3. An extremely hard-boiled engineer would use TRL 9 as the threshold for "exists". A soft-boiled engineer might acknowledge something at TRL 7 or 8, and maybe even TRL 6, as "existing" technology. Ideas on paper, analytic studies, little toys and prototypes that kinda-sorta work, these do not qualify as "existing" technology.

Comment: @DavidHammen We quite clearly DO have the technology, and there have been multiple detailed plans for Mars missions (so far unfunded) which make that fact abundantly clear.  NASA's plans for going to Mars in the 2030s (which are not, in fact, "plans" as much as they are "aspirations") are as much about budgets as they are anything else.  If the survival of the human species depended entirely on putting humans on Mars 24 months from now, that would happen, because we already have all the technology necessary for the trip. Nothing you've written yet contradicts that truth.

Comment: @Kirkaiya - You and I have very different opinions regarding what constitutes "existing technology". Here's an incomplete list of what we don't know how to do: (1) Supply air, water, and food for a 20-24 month long mission. (2) Protect astronauts outside the Earth's magnetic sheidl against radiation for that span of time. (3) Land a large spacecraft on Mars. (MSL pressed the limits, and it wasn't large). (4) Precision landing on Mars. The current concept of precision landing isn't very precise. (5) ISRU. (6) Taking off from Mars. (7) Fuel depots in space. And now I've hit the character limit.

Comment: @DavidHammen I disagree with your list completely.  We absolutely do know how to supply air, water and food for a 2-year trip, it would merely be expensive. We absolutely know how to protect from radiation (water or lead for example) it would merely be expensive. We already know how to land a large vehicle on Mars (propulsive landings), but again, expensive to launch a heavy vehicle to Mars.  As for precision, Apollo managed fine. You seem to think "technology" means "we have it all built".  That is absurd, and NOT the definition of "technology". You have failed to convince anyone.

Comment: @Kirkaiya - You and I have very different ideas on what "existing" means.  My idea is TRL 5. Anything less is pie in the sky. We do not know how to supply air, water, and food for a two+ year trip. If we already knew how to do it, this would not be one of NASA's Game Changing Development Plan projects. We do not know how to land a large vehicle on Mars. The Mars Science Laboratory pushed the limits on what we know how to do. As far as not convincing anyone, NASA has used the Technology Readiness Level as a metric for 25 years. They know researchers don't know what "we know how to do it" means.

Comment: @DavidHammen Your idea is wrong. Nobody currently has an electric car that can go 650 miles on a single charge, but we absolutely have the technology to build one; take a Tesla Model S, and fill the back seat with more batteries until the range is 650 miles. It wouldn't be elegant or cost-effective, but it's obvious that it could be done. Ditto for sending humans to Mars - NASA isn't focused on merely "getting humans to Mars", they've known they could do that for a decade. They're focused on finding a path to Mars that is affordable and very safe (<3% additional cancer risk, etc). You're wrong

Comment: @paul23 It's a problem of scale, not of fuel.  Did you read any of my sources?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could say the Dutch, but Mars One is a Dutch corporate venture, not a government program.

Answer (score 0):

Laura Seward Forczyk gives [one of the better summaries of potential manned Mars missions](http://laurasspaceonspace.blogspot.com/2015/03/mars-or-bust-mars-one-busted-and-other.html) I've seen lately -- especially concerning Mars One.  In summary, Mars One is a gimmick and no one is going to Mars in the next 15 years and probably longer.  Most of what you hear otherwise is hype.  The best chance for someone to do it in our lifetime is probably Elon Musk -- and he's a long shot.

Comment: Hilarious.  For all your unsupported criticism against my 'flawed' explanation that we can't give an exact date you post an opinion piece and say it's a summary of manned missions (which it isn't) as an answer?  Even Laura says,  "The technology to do this is in the works but it will take us decades before we figure out how to do it."  Which is pretty much what I posted 2 years ago.

Comment: See my comment under tomByrer's answer.  I'm sorry my downvote has bothered you for 2 years.  It's not personal.

Comment: Mars One and blind dishonest discussions about the complexities of space travel are what bother me.  I don't care about you, sorry.

Comment: I'm not even sure what you disagree with me on.  We have the same opinion on the answer to the original question...